# Composer's auto load doesn't work after deploy

Tags: php, composer-php, vendor

I have a small php project and a very cheap hosting that doesn't give SSH option. I'm using composer for the autoloader functionality, and have to upload the vendor folder as well, because composer is not a thing either. After I run my script I get errors for classes not being found, so the problem is in the auto load. What can I do?

Comment: You could try a third party auto loader, if that is all you are using composer for then why not.  Just so happens I have one handy on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Autoloader) (that I wrote) It has much better debugging then the one bundled with Composer that alone might help you figure out what you did wrong....  Awkwardly enough you can get it with composer ... lol

Comment: Just as a guess, if your developing on windows and moving to linux.  The 2 biggest things to look for are capitalization (windows is case insensitive, linux is not). And, file permissions.  Probably 90% of the time if something works on Windows and not Linux, it's gonna be one of those 2 things.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow. This is my project - https://github.com/DvDty/TheEliteNotifier

Comment: Cool just glancing at it, it looks nice code wise.  Yea there is nothing wrong with using your own autoloader.  It's generally frowned on as most people don't follow the PSR4 standards which can make it hard to integrate in existing projects.  But just from a dependency stand point, Composer can be a bit intimidating to non-programmers, so one less thing to install is always a good thing..

Comment: I added my own loader. TIL it's not even hard to do it, just have to understand what is happening exactly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, I like developing my own stuff, then I might use some other libraries if I don't have time to update or write my own, but I always try to understand what stuff does.  Of course I been coding PHP a long time, about 9 years.